# PostgreSQL searching by jsonb fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-10, postgresql-json

In my PostgreSQL database I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE referral_datas (
    id integer,
    referrals jsonb
);

INSERT INTO referral_datas (id, referrals)
  VALUES (1, '[{"risk_score": "1"}]');

INSERT INTO referral_datas (id, referrals)
  VALUES (2, '[{"risk_score": "2"}]');

INSERT INTO referral_datas (id, referrals)
  VALUES (3, '[{"risk_score": "3"}]');
```

and the following query:

```
select * from referral_datas where referrals @> '[{"risk_score": "2"}]'
```

which returns following results:

```
    id | referrals
----------------------------------------
    2  | [{"risk_score":"2"}]
```

Query works fine but I want have a query that will find referral datas with `risk_score = 2` or `risk_score = 1`

so the result of the query should be:

```
    id | referrals
----------------------------------------
    1  | [{"risk_score":"1"}]
    2  | [{"risk_score":"2"}]
```

How can I do this in PostgreSQL?

Here is db fiddle that You can experiment with:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pP3AudKgUs242YJjR9mxaS/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could *expand* jsonb array before filtering. Use `jsonb_array_elements` to it:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    referral_datas c 
    JOIN jsonb_array_elements(c.referrals) AS foo(bar) ON TRUE
WHERE
    foo.bar->>'risk_score' IN ('1', '2');
```

Please note that this probably won't use any index you've created on `referral_datas.referrals`. That's ok if your data isn't so huge. Use carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this query:

```
SELECT id,referrals FROM referral_datas
WHERE referrals->0->>'risk_score' IN ('1','2');
```

Comment: referrals array can have multiple objects so this will not work.